# How to insert show code in edit form using ActiveAdmin Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Questions View Page where the user can view all the questions. Also, I have a link to "Create New Question", which when clicked will be allowing the user to add new questions.

And the code for this is as below:

```
ActiveAdmin.register QuestionType do

menu :if => proc{ !current_admin_user.present? }

permit_params :name

index do 
selectable_column
column :name
actions
end

show do 
 attributes_table :name
end

form do |f|
 f.inputs "Add Question type" do
   f.input :name
 end
 f.actions
end

end
```

My code is working fine, but I want to display all the questions at the time of adding a new Question. I want to show all the questions below the submit of "add new question" button, so that the user can see existing questions too. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder **admin_partials** under the folder **app/views/**

Create a file **_question_form.html.erb** in **admin_partials** folder so that the directory structure looks like as **app/views/admin_partials/_question_form.html.erb**

Put the code below in that file:-

```
<%= form_for @question_type, :url => admin_question_types_path , :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
 <fieldset class="inputs">
  <ol>
   <% unless @question_type.nil? %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :id, @question_type.id %>
   <% end %>
   <%  f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |y| %>
    <%= y %> <br />
   <% end %>

   <li class="string input required stringish">
     <%= f.label :name, :class => 'label'%>
     <div class="controls">
       <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
     </div>
   </li>

   <li class="string input required stringish">
     <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
       <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            admin_question_types_path, :class => 'btn' %>
   </li>

  </ol>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>

<h3>All Question types</h3>
<ol>
 <% QuestionType.all.each do|question_type| %>
  <li><span><%= question_type.name %></span><span><%= link_to "Show", question_type  %></span><span><%= link_to "Delete", question_type, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %></span></li>
 <% end %>
</ol>
```

Edit this file as:-

```
ActiveAdmin.register QuestionType do

menu :if => proc{ !current_admin_user.present? }

permit_params :name

index do 
selectable_column
column :name
actions
end

show do 
 attributes_table :name
end

form :partial => "admin_partials/question_form"

end
```

Comment: its working perfect, tnx, Can I give links to edit,show along with the name in show part

Comment: in the form where all question types is displayed?

Comment: `<li><%= question_type.name %></li>` this line is displaying the questionType, along with this I want to provide links to edit or delete this QuestionType.